# Arduino Uno coding problem voltage varying

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I was wondering whether anyone could help me... I am using an Arduino Uno and I am writing my code in the Arduino IDE. I am trying to implement the code so that the output voltage can be varied from 0 - 5 volts using 2 pushbuttons. I want to be able to increment the voltage by +0.5 volts from 0-5 volts every time I push Button A. Also I want to decrement the voltage by -0.5 volts from 5-0V every time I push Button B.

Example: (push Button A): output voltage 0.5: (push Button A): output voltage 1.0 etc.

So far when I upload my code the LED as my test for output just flickers between 2 - 4 volts. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am not that good at coding so any help would be awesome.

Here is my code.

```
int PWMPin = 6; // output pin supporting PWM
int buttonApin = 8; // buttonA to pin 9 PWM
int buttonBpin = 10; // buttonB to pin 10 PWM
float value = 0; // read the value at 0
float fadeValue = value;
float counter = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonApin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonBpin, INPUT);
  pinMode(PWMPin, OUTPUT);
} 
void loop() {
  int port = analogRead(0);
  port = map(port, 0, 10, 0, 255);
  analogWrite(6, port);
  if (digitalRead(buttonApin) == LOW, fadeValue) {
    if (counter >= 10) {
      counter = 10;
    }
    // fade from min to max in increments of 25.5 points: basically (0.5 volts)
    for(fadeValue = 0 ; fadeValue <= 255; fadeValue +=25.5) {
      counter = fadeValue;
      // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
      analogWrite(PWMPin, fadeValue);
      delay(100);
    }
  }
  if (digitalRead(buttonBpin) == LOW, fadeValue) {
    if (counter <= 0) {
      counter = 0;
    }
    // fade from max to min in increments of 25.5 points: basically (0.5 volts)
    for(fadeValue = 255 ; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -=25.5) {
      counter = fadeValue;
      // sets the value (range from 0 to 255):
      analogWrite(PWMPin, fadeValue);
      delay(100);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a LED to test your output instead of, say, a DMM?

Comment: Because it would be the same thing when I connect it to a different source I will still be able to vary voltage IF i can get this running.

Comment: Varying the voltage on a LED does almost nothing.

Comment: okay so what would use for an output?

Comment: Something that gives you an actual number.

Comment: obviously if I get the Light to turn on I get light I can dim the light an brighten the light according to how often I push the button to the max 5v i think I'll be fine but what about my code? how bad is it?

Comment: "obviously if I get the Light to turn on I get light I can dim the light an brighten the light according to how often I push the button..." No. You can't. This is a LED.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - **that is not true** - it's not an LED by itself, it's an LED in series with a resistance (external or internal).  And that means that the current which flows, and hence brightness, is a function of overall voltage.  Of course, most LED dimmers work with a fixed, optimal voltage and varying duty cycle.  It's an open question here if the Arduino's PWM output should be considered smoothed, or pulsed - that depends on the frame rate, and capacitance in comparison to load.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: The 25ohm resistance of the output is going to be unnoticeable at best.

Comment: On the contrary, the resistance *whatever it is* is going to be extremely noticeable - either the LED fails, or if it doesn't, that effective resistance is what is setting the operating current and preventing it from doing so.  Given the maximum current rating I expect it's a bit higher than 25 ohms effective *when operating in excess of rated current*.

Comment: The statement `if (digitalRead(buttonApin) == LOW, fadeValue)` is equivalent to `if (digitalRead(fadeValue)`. I guess that's not what you wanted to do. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of very basic things wrong with your code - things that aren't doing what you think, or you just telling it completely the wrong things.

Start by formatting your code properly (INDENTS!) and match up all your brackets.  You'll soon see what I see as far as what is wrong.

I'll give you some clues:

---

```
{  
if (digitalRead(buttonApin) == LOW, counter)
```

Where to I start with that one...?

---

```
for(int fadeValue = 0 ; fadeValue <= 255; fadeValue +=25.5)    
  counter = fadeValue;   
  digitalWrite(PWMPin, fadeValue);
```

C is not Python!

---

```
digitalWrite(PWMPin, fadeValue);
```

Writing an analog value to a digital pin?!

---

```
Serial.println(PWMPin);
```

Printing the pin number - now what is the point of that?

---

```
... fadeValue += 25.5 ...
```

Adding a float to an integer - bad practice (and ultimately pointless) - pick one, float or integer, and stick to it.

---

And then there is the whole logic of your program. I can't work out what it's supposed to be achieving.  It looks like you've tried to get it to do all sorts of parts of different things and not got it to do anything at all.  Strip it right out and get it to do ONE thing - provide a specific, STATIC, voltage.  Then add in some way of changing that voltage afterwards.

Comment: I dont get it? what brackets should I take out

Comment: You have brackets where you shouldn't have, and you're lacking brackets where you should have them.

Comment: And that's just a start...

Comment: That's no help at all.  Please edit the code in your original question so I can see it in context

Comment: Yes I was going to put it in this comment and It was too long my bad I'm editing it now

Comment: uploaded new code now

Comment: Your program is still complete gibberish I am sorry to say. It looks like you have copied and pasted bits of other code without first understanding how that code works, and then interspersed it with some random bits that you think look like C but aren't. Go back to basics and get an LED to light at a specific brightness.

Comment: You forgot to add. It's useless to scale an analog output by a loop without delays!

Comment: Arduino IDE has autoformat function, it does most of the job itself that way.